# Parameter @p_appraisal_period_id was not defined for stored procedure sp_StatusReport_GoalCompletionPercentageBySup

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am preparing a callable statement in JAVA to execute a stored procedure on SQL server:

```
CallableStatement st = connection.prepareCall ({ call sp_StatusReport_GoalCompletionPercentageBySup ( ? ) });
st.setInt(paramName, 0);  //paramName=@p_appraisal_period_id
```

However I get the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parameter @p_appraisal_period_id was not defined for stored procedure sp_StatusReport_GoalCompletionPercentageBySup.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:227)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.findColumn(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:1396)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.setInt(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:2579)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.datasources.JDBCDataSource.prepareCallableStatement(JDBCDataSource.java:241)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.datasources.JDBCDataSource.getResults(JDBCDataSource.java:102)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.dataservices.SPDataService.getResults(SPDataService.java:56)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.application.AbstractWidget.getResults(AbstractWidget.java:71)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.application.Page.getResults(Page.java:165)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.application.Application.getResults(Application.java:463)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.application.ApplicationManager.getResults(ApplicationManager.java:347)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:632)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   com.abzooba.uba.datasources.DataSourceException: Parameter @p_appraisal_period_id was not defined for stored procedure sp_StatusReport_GoalCompletionPercentageBySup.
>       at com.abzooba.uba.datasources.JDBCDataSource.getResults(JDBCDataSource.java:154)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.dataservices.SPDataService.getResults(SPDataService.java:56)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.application.AbstractWidget.getResults(AbstractWidget.java:71)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.application.Page.getResults(Page.java:165)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.application.Application.getResults(Application.java:463)
>       at com.abzooba.uba.application.ApplicationManager.getResults(ApplicationManager.java:347)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:632)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I am fetching database metadata from connection string:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
if (dbMetaData != null){
        ResultSet rs = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns (null, null, sp_name.toUpperCase(), "%");
        while (rs.next())
            paramInfo.put(rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(6));
        rs.close();
    }
```

It returns me `@p_appraisal_period_id`.

Comment: Try `st.setInt("p_appraisal_period_id", 0);` instead of `st.setInt("@p_appraisal_period_id", 0);`

Comment: @GordThompson that does work. But while fetching columns metadata, it returns `@p_appraisal_period_id` instead of `p_appraisal_period_id`. I have edited the question and added the code. Please see. Thnx